# 暖かい・食べ物 / 例えば、火が作れる場合は→を起こせば冬にぬくもりが作れるし / 燃やしてしまう可能性もある

Tags: grammar, kanji, semantics

I'm writing small compositions on a regular basis and putting them on italki, so that someone proofreads it and makes corrections to it. Recently, I posted **[this](https://www.italki.com/notebook/3534043/entry/823680)** and got a rather comprehensive answer. I do have some issues understanding this answer though, since it’s written Japanese.

First:  (Line 12 of the correction)

> ・火を起こす(condition）→暖かい・食べ物を焼けるし温められる…..

What does this little dot ・ between 暖かい and たべもの mean?

Second: (Line 7 of the correction)

> 例えば、火が作れる場合は→を起こせば冬にぬくもりが作れるし…

What I wanted to say in my original sentence was:

> "When you are able to make fire, you can…"

In my Japanese version, I wanted to preserve this concept of the ability being the condition. In my opinion, this meant that I somehow had to open up a conditional clause, and at the same time get a potential verb form or something of similar semantics into this conditional clause.
At first I decided that I couldn’t use both the potential verb form and the conditional verb form in one and the same verb (I might be wrong of course, but I just don’t know better). Then I thought of a workaround and ultimately decided for a solution using 場合は (…ことができたら also came to mind, but the overly literal translation "concerning the case that you are able to…" seemed very fitting, so I went with 場合は).

If I understand the improved version of the proofreader correctly, then it means “When you make fire, you can…”. While this is perfectly okay as well, I just wanted to know whether it's possible to express exactly what I described above in Japanese. And if it's possible, how would you express it?

Third: (Line 8 of the correction)

> 燃やしてしまう可能性もある

=> What is this 性? What is its reading?

I think　さが would be the most fitting, but maybe I got it completely wrong.

Comment: All know for sure is that the 性 in 可能性 probably means `nature` as in `the nature of this situation` or something like that...  
 I could very well be wrong though... 
  http://jisho.org/word/%E5%8F%AF%E8%83%BD%E6%80%A7

Comment: For the difference between 暖かい and 温かい, we already have brilliant answers: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/5383/9831 and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/213/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First: (Line 12 of the correction) ・火を起こす(condition）→暖かい・食べ物を焼けるし温められる….. what does this little dot ・ between 暖かい and たべもの mean?

The dot is a comma as is shown below.

"し" in 食べ物をやけるし means "and", then, "→暖かい・食べ物を焼けるし温められる" means as "→ 暖かい, 食べ物を焼ける and 温められる".

> Second: ... I just wanted to know wether its possible to express exactly what I described above in japanese. And if its possible, how would you express it?

It's possible.

My trial is like:

> **You**: 例えば、火が作れる場合は冬にぬくもりが作れし、食べ物が暖められる。
> **The proofreader**: 例えば、火を起こせば冬にぬくもりが作れるし、食べ物が温められる。
> **Me**: 例えば、火が作れる場合は冬にぬくもりが**得{え}られ**、食べ物**も**温められる。

I'll show you how I made my trial.
Since the repetition of the same word in one sentence is not so good also in Japanese, I changed the latter "作る" into "得る". In addition, because "し" which represents "and" is not a very neat way of saying, I used "も" in the latter part of the sentence to keep the same meaning of your sentence.

> Third: (Line 8 of the correction) 燃やしてしまう可能性もある => What is this 性? What is its reading? I think　さが

性 could be read as せい or さが, and 性 in 可能性｛かのうせい｝ is read せい and it functions to make 可能｛かのう｝ *possible* into a noun meaning *possibility*.
As for this question, I agree with Seesawscene's answer.

---

## Bonus

### Difference between 暖められる and 温められる

I'll tell you why the proofreader and I changed 暖められる into 温められる in your original version in Japanese.
As you know, the two words are potential forms or passive forms of 暖める and 温める.
So I will explain the difference between the basic form 暖める and 暖める. They are also transitive verbs and are used to warm something, and their intransitive forms are 暖まる and 温まる as you know.

The difference between 暖める and 温める is explained in detail [here](http://www.chigai.org/%E3%80%8C%E6%9A%96%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B%E3%80%8D%E3%81%A8%E3%80%8C%E6%B8%A9%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B%E3%80%8D%E3%81%AE%E9%81%95%E3%81%84/), [here](http://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/term/029.html) and [here](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1447727184), but they seem not to be easy to understand for those studying Japanese, and to make matters worse they are written in Japanese.
So, I will try to explain the contents of the above articles comprehensively while correcting deviations from my understanding on which I usually use them properly in an easy-to-understand manner using images.

違いの最も重要なことは、あたためられる物の「**芯の温度あるいは中心の温度**」です。
The most important key word or key point of the difference is "**the temperature of [芯]{しん} *the core* or *center***" of something to be warmed.

暖と温の漢字を適宜使い分けながら説明をします。どのようにこの漢字を使っているか着目してください。
I'll proceed with my explanation while using the kanjis of 暖 and 温 properly. I hope you to pay attention to how these *kanji*s are used properly.

冷えた体で、あなたが暖炉（fireplace）の前に行き暖を取ると体が暖まります、しかし、背中はまだ寒い。これは、何故おきるのでしょうか。
If you go to the fireplace and warm yourself at it with a cold body, the body will gradually warm up, but the back is still cold. Why does this happen?

その答えは、体の前面は暖炉の暖かさ（「放射熱または輻射熱」という）ですぐに暖まりますが、暖かさがまだ体の芯に届いていない、もちろん背中には届いていないからです。
It is because that the front of the body warms up quickly with the warmth of the fireplace (called "radiant heat"), but the warmth has yet to reach the core of the body, needless to say about the back of the back.

すなわち暖炉の熱がまだ体の中心まで伝導していないことで体全体が温まっていないためです。
In other words, that is because the heat of the fireplace has not yet reached the center of the body, so the whole body has not been warmed up completely.

体の表面は暖かいが体の芯は温まっていないというのが、暖炉に暖まっている途中の状態です。
It is the state in the middle of warming yourself at the fireplace when the body's surface or the front part of the body is warm but the body's core is not yet warm.

食べ物を温めるときも同じことが言えます。お鍋に食べ物を入れて、あるいは電子レンジに食べ物を入れて温めるためには、適当な時間を掛けて、食べ物の表面ではなく、芯の温度が適温になるために十分な時間を掛ける必要があります。
The same can be said when warming food. In order to put food in a pot or in a microwave oven to heat or reheat it, it is necessary to spend an adequate amount of time to heat not the surface but the core of food to become the optimum temperature.

日本を象徴する一つとして温泉があることをご存知でしょう。温泉にゆっくりつかると体の芯まで温まります。温泉を出てしばらくは、少し涼しいところにいても体の芯まで温まっているので引き続き汗が出るほどです。
You know that there is a hot spring as one of the symbols of Japan. If you have a good long soak in a hot spring, you could warm your body's core. For a while after getting out of the hot spring, you would experience to continue to break sweat because the body's core is warm even if you are in a little cooler place.

暖炉や太陽のような熱源に当たっているときは、たしかに暖かですが、一旦これらが遮断されると暖かさが終わります。従って、「暖」という字は、暖かさを感じている側でなく、熱源そのものを表現するのにふさわしいのではないかと思っています。言い換えますと、「暖」という字は、「暖炉が暖かい」とか「太陽が暖かい」というように、「暖まる」「暖める」とかではなく、「暖かい」という形容詞で熱源の様子を表現するのに一番向いていると思います。
When we are facing the heat of the fireplace or the heat of the sun, which are heat sources, we feel warm, but the warmth ends when the heat sources are shut off. Therefore, "暖" is more suitable, I think, to be used to express the heat sources rather than to express the side feeling the warmth of them.
In other words, "暖" is most suitable for being used as in the adjective "暖かい" rather than in "暖める" or "暖まる" to express the state of the heat sources like in "暖炉が暖かい" or "太陽が暖かい".

一方、「温」という字は、熱源からの熱が伝わってあるものが芯まで温まる、その結果、熱源が取り除かれても温かさはしばらく保持されます。従って、「温」と言う字は、「温泉で温まる」とか「食べ物を温める」というように熱を得たものの温度が上昇する様子を動詞で表現するのに向いていると思う。
On the other hand, "温" describes the warmth of the heat transferred to the core of something or somebody from the heat source, so that the warmth is retained for a while even if the heat source is removed. Therefore, I think "温" is suitable for expressing how the temperature rises as in a verb "温まる" or "温める" used in such as "温泉で温まる" or "食べ物を温める".

最後に覚え方の秘訣を伝授します。
暖炉の「暖」は、体の表面が暖かい、一方、温泉の「温」は体の芯まで温まるです。料理は温泉と同じで芯まで温めましょう。
Lastly, I will teach you the knack of how to memorize them.
"暖" in "暖炉 *fireplace*" is used to warm on the surface of the body, while "温" in "温泉 *hot spring*" is used to warm up to the core of the body. Let's cook up to the core of the food same as a hot spring does.

[image]

Comment: jisho.orgに`可能性`の読み方が「かのうせい」と書いてあるから少し混乱してます。

Comment: @ajsmart: I'm sorry, I made a mistake. Yes 可能性 is read as かのうせい. 可（か）能（のう）性（せい）

Comment: I think it would help the OP if someone explained the difference between his use of 暖められる and 温められる.

Comment: @A.Ellett: > the difference between his use of 暖められる and 温められる. http://imijiten.com/kanjiimi/219/ Give me a time to explain it further.

Comment: @mackygoo It's not that I need it explained, but I think it would be helpful to the OP to have it explained.  But that's a great link.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should read the answer again now. 
Because the writer has proofread their typo. 
Your first question seemed to be typo.

可能性（かのうせい）＝possibility

可能＝possible